# Double to int implicit conversion in mingw32

Tags: c, mingw32

I can't explain the behaviour of the following program (compiled with gcc on mingw 32 bits). I'm aware of the possible precision loss when implicitly converting from double to int, but I would expect the two cases to give the same output since it is doing the exact same operations. Why are the two outputs different?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int table[3] = {2, 3, 4};
    int i, N;

    N = 0;
    N += table[0] * pow(100, 0);
    N += table[1] * pow(100, 1);
    N += table[2] * pow(100, 2);
    printf("%d\n", N);

    N = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        N += table[i] * pow(100, i);
    printf("%d\n", N);

    return 0;
}

//output: 
40302
40300
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `pow(100, 0)` `pow(100, 1)` and `pow(100, 2)` the compiler replaces the function calls with constants (`1, 100, 10000`), but with `pow(100, i)` it has to actually call the function at runtime (because of the variable `i` being passed as argument), resulting with two results of `pow` in the form `0.99999999` and `99.999999` instead of `1` and `100` (or any 2 of the 3). When truncating to int after the multiply you "lose" two units.

This is another example of why converting to `int` from `double` is just **pure evil**: very hard to find subtle bugs in your program (not compiler bugs).

Btw, I am surprised that the compiler with `O2` didn't unroll the loop, propagate the constants and reach the same optimization (replacing the function call with constant results).

Btw2 Scratch that, I am surprised that the compiler didn't just replace all you code with only two calls to `printf`.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the C standard actually doesn't specify the precision of "pow()", not even that "pow()" has to give the same result for pow(0) and pow(i) with i=0. That was really surprising for me but makes sense to allow for optimizations on very small embedded systems.

Comment: Interestingly, the compiler [optimized this away when the loop has only two iterations](https://godbolt.org/z/q3GzW6).

Comment: @Groo Your link points to a different compiler (gcc 9.2 x86-64), so it is not really surprising that the result is different. Even with three iterations in the loop the result of my question cannot be reproduced with gcc 9.2, my question was specific to mingw-32bits GCC.